Adding new transforms to constraint target of camera. Without affecting original animation
I am working with a camera that has a Child Of and Track To constraint targeting an object in motion.
That animation of the camera with the constraints is good, however I need to apply additional transforms to the moving object, without it changing the cameras current animation. While baking the animation is the obvious solution to this, I want to keep the constraints applied.
Is there a NLA method to store the camera animation (as it currently is), and make change to it's target, without the constraints having to be removed?

Duplicate your object, make the original invisible, the camera will keep following it, and give the new keyframes to the copy?

Duplicate your object, make the original invisible, the camera will keep following it, and give the new keyframes to the copy.
